# Sub Array with range swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript, sub-array

I am getting the whole array from core-data, trying to make sub-array with range but it's not working my code is

```
var list : [FeedbackRound] = []

list = try CoreDataInterface.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [FeedbackRound]

if let feedbackRoundArray:[FeedbackRound] = list {
    let arrRecordChunks:[FeedbackRound]  = feedbackRoundArray[0...2]                    
}
```

It's show following error msg -  **cannnot subscript a value of type [any] with an index of type countableclosedRange**

just for sake of information array is not empty.

Comment: Just remove the explicit type annotation and you'll see that `feedbackRoundArray[0...2]` doesn't give you a `[FeedbackRound]`.

Comment: i did try with feedbackRoundArray[startIndex...endIndex] , but no luck

Comment: This will definitely not compile even after the issue was resolved.

Comment: i think stackoverflow is not right platform for me anymore